# Cannot resolve : Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory

Tags: command-prompt

I am using visual studio community 2017, and I am tryying to build ninja from developer command prompt . Every time I try exception  is thrown

`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory` .

I referred some other sites and I installed these packages along with

1) desktop development with c++

2) VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools

3) Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)

4) Windows Universal CRT SDK

Kindly suggest some solution for this ? Am I missing any dependency packages?

Comment: Check `Additional Include Directories` in a project properties, add fully qualified directory name (you can find one using `where.exe /R c:\ corecrt.h` from an open command prompt). Maybe `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt`

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply, I have tried putting "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" into system path, nothing seems to working. If there is any other solution kindly let me know.

Comment: I don't mean _system path_  but `Additional Include Directories` in a particular project properties _inside_  Visual Studio.  Open a project in VS, menu _PROJECT_ => _projectName Properties…_, dialog _projectName Property Pages_ left pane => _Configuration Properties_ => _C/C++_ => _General_. Another approach: `/I` (Additional Include Directories) compiler option, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/73f9s62w(v=vs.120)